# Should I include paper-styles/classes/typography.html to use Polymer's typography classes?

Tags: css, polymer, web-component

At the moment, in my elements.html I am doing:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/classes/typography.html">
```

Note that I include "classes". This way, in my HTML page (NOT in a component!) I can have:

```
<paper-material elevation="4">
  <h1 class="paper-font-display1">This is actually rendered</h1>
</paper-material>
```

Is this a horrible way to go about it? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "classes" variation of Polymer styles uses "/deep/" selectors and as a result you will get a deprecation warning from Chrome. For that reason I recommend that you avoid the "classes" variant.  The non-classes variation use css mixins which is the approach that is recommended for [Polymer 1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins).

For example an element definition could do this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
<dom-module>
  <style include="shared-styles">
    .myCaptionStyle {
      @apply(--paper-font-caption);
      color: var(--secondary-text-color);
    }
  </style>
</dom-module>
```

Also, take a look at how shared styles work. You can create a shared css class definition out of Polymer's css components and share that with your own elements rather than, or in addition to, using Polymer's mixin directly.  As a reference look at how the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) uses shared-styles.

Comment: Beware that there is a timing issue with the this element and your theme file, if it defines the same variables.  This is not so much a problem for typography, but for default-theme.html it certainly is.  Polymer mixes items with the same name so that the last to load (not request to load, but actually finish downloading) wins.  A large element (like paper-toolbar) which uses it can be slow to load, whereas your own theme file can load very quickly and then be overwritten.

Comment: @jptknta Did you see my sentence, "This way, in my HTML page (NOT in a component!) I can have:" I was taking about styling a bit of HTML in a page, more than styling components...

Comment: @akc42 I am confused... were you commenting on my code? Or jptkna...?

Comment: @jptknta I don't see a /deep/ in the classes variation...?

Comment: @jptknta both really.  I am really wary about using the paper-style elements because of the timing issue.  I had to resort to injecting a html import for my theme after dom ready to get it to work for me

Comment: The /deep/ still appears in the polymer layout classes.  I went through the process of removing all use of Polymer style classes and switching to mixins in order avoid the deprecation warning and be consistent through out my code. I don't see use of /deep/ in the typography classes . So you may be okay using classes if it is limited to typography.

Comment: @akc42 Are you able to provide a fiddle for the timing issue?

Comment: @Merc look at the discussion here   https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/issues/93, and also follow the link to issue #3348 in the Polymer/Polymer repo

Comment: @akc42 Your turn to have a look. I tried to reproduce it, but failed. Have a look at my writeup. Please let me know what I did wrong!